# Using bash script inside if statement

Tags: bash

I was asked to write a simple script in bash that would be used inside if statements. It takes one argument and depending on result of calculations inside this script, it either passes the if or not. It should be something like function returning true or false inside if statement.

It would be used like this:

```sh
if ./script_name argument ; then
     ...
fi
```

Inside said script I tried making a function that does required calculations, that was using `return 0` or `return 1`, but I never got satisfying results - despite calculations being correct, the if statement always was executed. Then I switched to 'true' or 'false', but with same results.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

function function_name () {

# calculations...

if [ something ]
then
    true
else
    false
fi
}
```

Using above script in a way:

```sh
if ./script_name argument; then echo "True"; else echo "False"; fi
```

always prints True, no matter the argument. No errors. Calculations are correct - tried it without `return`, but with `echo 0 / echo 1` in terminal and it printed both of them accordingly to the argument (correctly).

Comment: Where do you call `function_name()`? If the function call is not last command in your script, you cannot expect the exit code to be equal to the function's return value.

Comment: All your script does is define a function. The function definition is successful, so it returns 0. You never call your function anywhere.

Comment: Adding function call at the end solved the problem. Sorry for dumb question, I'm still learning how to write scripts - I never used a function in bash before. Thanks for help!